# Возможно ли использовать JSX компоненты в TypeScript (TSX)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2017, jsx

Для различных библиотек `JavaScript` предумотрены Types Definitions что бы эти библиотеки можно было использовать в `TypeScript`.
А если я хочу использовать пакет к которому нету Types `(*.d.ts)` файлов? Могу ли я это сделать?
Пока пробуя использовать такую библиотеку страница выдаёт:

> ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/components/Test.tsx:5:36 
>       TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-router-role-authorization'.
>   '.../node_modules/react-router-role-authorization/dist/index.js'
>   implicitly has an 'any' type.   Try `npm install
>   @types/react-router-role-authorization` if it exists or add a new
>   declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module
>   'react-router-role-authorization';` ERROR in [at-loader]
>   ./ClientApp/routes.tsx:62:12

Итого: Возможно ли использовать библиотеки без `d.ts`, и если да, то как?
Если вообще стоит ли это делать, если это возможно?

Работаю на `VisualStudio 2017`.
В `tsconfig.json` стоит `"allowJs": true` и  `"jsx": "react"`.

**Добавлено:**
После ответа @Daniel Khoroshko эта ошибка исчезла, теперь есть другая

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';
const { RoleAwareComponent } = require('react-router-role-authorization');

export class Test extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, {}> {

    public render() {
        return <div><Test2 /></div>;
    }
}

export class Test2 extends RoleAwareComponent  {
    allowedRoles: string[];
    userRoles: string[];

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.allowedRoles = ['user'];
        this.userRoles = ['user','super-user'];
    }

    public render() {
        return <div style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}>
            Test!
        </div>;
    }
}
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

> ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/components/Test.tsx:11:21 
>       TS2605: JSX element type 'Test2' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.   Property 'setState' is missing in type 'Test2'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы видимо импортируете компонент используя `import from` или `import =´`.

А с библиотеками без типов надо так:

```
const { AuthorizedComponent } = require('react-router-role-authorization');

class Test extends AuthorizedComponent {
  render() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

`webpack: Compiled successfully.`

Comment: Да, именно так и импортирую. Спасибо, буду пробовать. Но нигде не могу найти, почитать в чём разница этих команд импортирования, не подскажите где можно это прочитать?

Comment: Могу только сказать, что через import тайпскрипт ожидает на входе или тайпскрипт тайпинги или непосредственно тайпскрипт модули. Он их транспилирует как и бабель. А require это обычная фунция node.js. Насчёт почитать могу только посоветовать (наверное уже классический) TypeScript Deep Dive, хотя не уверен, есть ли там про импорт. https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/